# Help with Verse Identification -- 'Jesus has not yet returned because...'

Tags: life-of-jesus, second-coming, verse-identification

I have a particular verse in mind that I can't seem to remember. The gist is: 'Jesus has not yet returned for the sake of those who have yet to be added to his kingdom...'

It's something along those lines; if anyone knows what I am referencing I'd greatly appreciate a verse reference.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe Revelation 6:11?

Comment: Or [Mark 13:20](https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/mar/13/20/t_conc_970020)  cp. [Matt. 24:22](https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/mat/24/22/t_conc_953022)?

Comment: Matt 24:22 was my guess as well.

Answer (score 4):

I believe these are the two main candidates for what you are after:

> And this gospel of the kingdom will be preached in the whole world as a testimony to all nations, and then the end will come. - [Matthew 24:14 NIV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2024%3A14&version=NIV)
>
> The Lord is not slow in keeping his promise, as some understand slowness. Instead he is patient with you, not wanting anyone to perish, but everyone to come to repentance. - [2 Peter 3:9 NIV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20pet%203%3A9&version=NIV)

Comment: Yes, thank you! I was looking for the 2 Peter verse. It seems I was confounding different verses, but nonetheless - thank you!